# How to get the center and the axes of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

Get the center and the semimajor/semiminor axes of the following ellipses:

$$x^2-6x+4y^2=16$$

$$2x^2 - 4x+3y^2+6y=7$$

How would one get these? I have no clue. I have a problem with merely rewriting these in the traditional ellipse equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2-6x+4y^2=16$$

$$(x-3)^2-9+4y^2=16$$

$$(x-3)^2+4y^2=25$$

$$\frac{(x-3)^2}{25}+\frac{4y^2}{25}=1$$

$$\frac{(x-3)^2}{5^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\frac {5}{2})^2}=1$$

center is $O(3,0)$ AND axes are $a=5,b=5/2$, for second ellipse you can proceed similarly

Comment: The second one is really tough, I am stuck at $2(x-1)^2 + 3(y+1)^2 =12$ Am I on the right path or not?

Comment: yes. then divide by 12 and go further

Comment: Ok, I'll continue

Comment: $ M(1,-1)$ and $a=\sqrt{6}$ and $b=2$?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: @ZafarS.you are WELCOME

Answer (score 0):

I will do the first one:
$$
x^2 - 6 x + 4 y^2 = 16 \Rightarrow \left(x - 3\right)^2 + 4 y^2 = 25 \Rightarrow \frac{\left(x-3\right)^2}{5^2} + \frac{y^2}{\left(5/2\right)^2} = 1
$$

Now compare with equation 12 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html).